# STRING_SPLIT with a multiple-character separator?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, string-manipulation

SQL Server 2016 introduced [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) which is very fast and an excellent replacement for any homemade implementation people would roll before 2016.

Unfortunately, STRING_SPLIT only supports a single-character separator, which isn't always enough. Does anyone know of a good implementation that allows for using multiple characters in the separator?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, you can always use `REPLACE` to add a single-character delimiter to the argument before passing it in. You just need to choose a character that is unlikely/impossible to appear in the actual data. In this example, let's say your original data uses three pipes as a delimiter; I chose a Unicode character at random to substitute:

```
DECLARE 
  @olddelim nvarchar(32) = N'|||', 
  @newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (✏)

DECLARE @x nvarchar(max) = N'foo|||bar|||blat|||splunge';

SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@x, @olddelim, @newdelim), @newdelim);
```

I blogged about this in more detail here:

- [Dealing with the single-character delimiter in STRING_SPLIT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4940/dealing-with-the-singlecharacter-delimiter-in-sql-servers-stringsplit-function/)

---

Addressing a comment:

> bad solution. what if original string is like 'abc||pqr|||rst||123' (dynamic and can contain anything). desired o/p is  'abc||pqr' and 'rst||123' but your solution will give 'abc' 'pqr' 'rst' '123'

Okay, let's take your input and see if my solution gets the wrong output.

```
DECLARE 
  @olddelim nvarchar(32) = N'|||', 
  @newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (✏)

DECLARE @x nvarchar(max) = N'abc||pqr|||rst||123';

SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@x, @olddelim, @newdelim), @newdelim);
```

Result is:

```
abc||pqr
rst||123
```

And not what you must have assumed (but didn't test) this:

```
abc
pqr
rst
123
```

If your data is in a table, you could create a view so that you don't have to factor that expression into all of your queries.

---

If that doesn't work, because you might have a pencil (`✏`) in your data, and you can't find a single character in the [1,111,998 available Unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928054/61305) that won't be in your data set, you'll have to skip `STRING_SPLIT()`, since it is hard-coded to accept a single character delimiter ([`separator
Is a single character expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)).

Alternatives have been answered here [dozens of times before](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=string+split+sql+server), many before `STRING_SPLIT()` existed. Those methods still work.

I go over many alternatives, and also discuss the limitations in `STRING_SPLIT()`, in this series (I also discuss why you might consider not doing this in T-SQL using any method at all):

- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)
- [Comparing string splitting / concatenation methods](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat)
- [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : STRING_SPLIT()](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split)
- [STRING_SPLIT() in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [STRING_SPLIT() in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #2](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-2)

Comment: [Sometimes you just want to (mis)use string_split()](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36536050-string-split-delimit-on-long-strings) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JitendraPancholi You are _technically_ correct, but you're being unfair here because: **1)** the limitation is with `STRING_SPLIT`, not this particular work-around, **2)** this question is about `STRING_SPLIT`, not working with multi-character delimiters in general, **3)** in practice, it's safe to assume that certain characters won't be there, else it's just bad data, **4)** `NCHAR(31)` (record separator) should be safe since that is it's purpose, or `NCHAR(0)` with `, @newdelim COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2);` because if U+0000 (null) is in any string data, then there are bigger problems!

Comment: @SolomonRutzky `NCHAR(31)` is unit separator; record separator is `NCHAR(30)`; both are fine though.