# How do I format the output from OBJECT_DEFINITION so that it looks the same as sp_helptext?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, scripting, metadata

[object_definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql) and [sp_helptext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql) both return the source code of a stored procedure - but how can I use `object_definition` and get the source code including the line breaks as the `sp_helptext` currently does?

for example in the code below I create a stored procedure:

```
if OBJECT_ID('usp_radhe') is not null
   drop procedure usp_radhe
go
-- this procedure is just a test
-- it just returns a date in the past
-- how will I get its source code?
create procedure usp_radhe as 
begin
select dateadd(dd,-31,GETDATE()) 
end
```

using **sp_helptext** I get a nice view of the source code:

```
sp_helptext 'usp_radhe'
```

[image]

using **object_definition** I get the source code in a single line and that is not good for me:

```
select OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id('usp_radhe'))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this is exclusively a presentation issue of Management Studio. `OBJECT_DEFINITION` gives you back the exact string, including newline characters, but SSMS simply replaces those with spaces when it displays it in grid mode (to keep rows together). If you choose "Results to Text" (Ctrl-T) it will print the definition including newlines, but it will almost certainly be cut off, due to another limitation. Scott's answer in text mode will give you the definition as-is, presentation-wise, but `OBJECT_DEFINITION` is already "correct".

Comment: @JeroenMostert and Marcello: please see the **Update** section of [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229420/30859) as it pertains to a more recent development related to the "Results to Text" option :-)

Comment: Marcello: it just occurred to me that you never actually state in the question what your specific requirements are. How exactly are you going to use the output? Does it require line numbers along with the breaks, or just line breaks? Can you please update the question to clarify precisely what you're looking for? Thanks :)

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I liked the simplicity of [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229343/22336) and it works best in most environments. However, it is a variation of your answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/97350/22336) that I use mostly. Just line breaks a function that replaces `sp_helptext` basically.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky it is your procedure [here](http://pastebin.com/4UBfFZRv) that I use with a few teaks and I am most thankful to you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSSQL Server 2012 you can use a recursive function. E.g.:

```
/* Recursive function, to split an object (like stored procedure) into individual lines, with line number */
declare @delimiter nvarchar(2) = char(10);
declare @objectName sysname = 'dbo.MyObject'

;with CTE as (
  select 
    0 as linenr
  , object_definition( object_id(@objectName)) as def
  , convert(nvarchar(max), N'') as line
  union all
  select 
    linenr + 1
  , substring(def, charindex(@delimiter, def) + len(@delimiter), len(def) - (charindex(@delimiter, def)))
  , left(def, charindex(@delimiter, def)) as line
  from CTE
  where charindex(@delimiter, def) <> 0
 )
select linenr, line
from CTE
where linenr >= 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: this has worked for me best! other answers also worked but this one is so simple. I have not tested it against very large object_definitions though!

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem. First turn on this option of SSMS - it is turned off by default:

```
SSMS/Tools/Options/Query results/SQL Server/Results to grid/Retain CR/LF on copy or save
```

Close SSMS, and run it again to get it work.

I use this query to get the full text of object definitions:

```
create view v_get_text_of_objects as

select top 100000
  [name]
, definition = replace(replace(object_definition(object_id),'create view','alter view'),'create proc','alter proc')
, len = len(object_definition(object_id)) 
, type
, type_desc
, create_date   
, modify_date
from  sys.objects
where object_definition(object_id) like '%your text to find in sp%'
order by type, create_date desc
```

I like to display LEN of the sp text, so that I am sure it is not cropped.

Answer (score 5):

#### Update

With the release of [SSMS 18.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#182) on 2019-07-25, a new option became available. The option itself has existed for a long time, but with a change made in this release it became viable to use for the purpose requested here.

The specific change was increasing the number of characters retrieved when using "Result to Text" (by 8x). The documentation states (emphasis mine):

> Allow more data to be displayed (Result to Text) and stored in cells (Result to Grid). SSMS now allows ***up to 2M characters*** for both (***up from 256 K*** and 64 K, respectively). This also addressed the issue of users not able to grab more than 43680 chars from the cells of the grid.

Now the following displays as expected in "Results to Text":

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.sp_helptext'));
```

By default, the results are "column aligned" *and* "include column headers". With this combination of options, a line of dashes is used between the column headers and the results. The problem is that being column aligned, the dashes extend the full amount of what that column *could* possibly retrieve, which is likely to be 2,097,152 dashes (i.e. 2 MB worth). SSMS doesn't like super long lines and freezes for a second when scrolling up for that line to be in view.

You can get rid of that line by changing either (or both) of those two aforementioned options: either uncheck "Include column headers in the result set" and/or set "Output format" to "comma delimited". If you want these changes to be the new defaults (i.e. be remembered for next time), then you need to make the changes by going to Tools -> Options -> -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Text. If you want the changes to only be temporary, then right-click in the query editor tab/window, select "Query Options..." and go to Results -> Text.

I don't remember what the default value for "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column" was, but if it's not 2097152, then I suggested making that change the new default (i.e. via the "Tools" menu).

If the code is truncated due to being more than 2,097,152 bytes (characters in most cases), then a) yikes!, and b) use the XML method described below.

#### Original Answer

If you don't mind an extra line at the very top and very bottom that should be ignored, you can use the following to display the full text, as text and not as a result set:

```
SELECT 1 AS [Tag], 0 AS [Parent], NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.sp_helptext')) AS [Code!1!!CDATA]
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

It works the same across all versions starting with SQL Server 2005 (well, I assume from seeing that it worked on 2005, 2017, and 2019 CTP 2.2). I used a "CDATA" section (which, in turn, requires using the `EXPLICIT` mode of `FOR XML`) so that XML "special" characters `<`, `>`, `&`, and `"` would not be escaped as `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, and `&quot;`, respectively.

If you execute the T-SQL shown above, you will get back a one row, one column result set of an XML value. Click on the underlined XML value and it will open up in a new tab showing the full, properly formatted text (along with a first line of `<Code><![CDATA[` and a final line of `]]></Code>`):

```xml
<Code><![CDATA[
create procedure sys.sp_helptext
@objname nvarchar(776)
,@columnname sysname = NULL
as

set nocount on

declare @dbname sysname

... {redacted for space} ...

select Text from #CommentText order by LineId

CLOSE  ms_crs_syscom
DEALLOCATE  ms_crs_syscom
DROP TABLE  #CommentText

return (0) -- sp_helptext
]]></Code>
```

Depending on the size of the item you are "displaying", you might need to increase the SSMS setting for how much XML data it pulls down (else you might see truncated results). Go to:

**Tools | Options | Query Results | SQL Server | Results to Grid**

Then, under "Maximum Characters Retrieved", set "XML data" to (options are: 1 MB, 2 MB, 5 MB, and Unlimited). Then click the "OK" button.

Comment: Very nice @Solomon.  Thank you.  I was wondering if you could suggest a way to return the string from the XML as NVARCHAR(MAX)?

Comment: I'm thinking now to return the string as XML to C# and not deal with this conversion.  The purpose of converting to NV(MAX) was so the string could be returned to C# as JSON.  Using XML seems preferrable in this case

Comment: Xml worked.  Ha, thanks again :)

Comment: Hi @SteveC . Yer welcome, glad it worked for you. However, if you are not viewing it in SSMS, then why bother with any of this in the first place? Simply getting the return value from `OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'schema_name.object_name'))` should be sufficient. Meaning, converting that output to XML is  most likely an unnecessary step for your purposes; the only reason this method is being used in this context is to preserve formatting while viewing in SSMS.

Comment: It's for codegen which needs the formatting too.  Returning as string would then require fixing the format.  Your answer helped me move forward.  Thanks again

Comment: @SteveC Again, glad it's working, but I'm still confused ;-). Returning the output of `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` shouldn't remove any formatting, and should be identical to the XML except it wouldn't start with `<Code><![CDATA[` and end with `]]></Code>`. This question is specific to viewing the definition within SSMS, which flattens everything to one row (Results to Grid), or cuts off at 8k characters (using `PRINT`). Results to Text used to have a lower limit but now can return up to 2 MB: `SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.sp_helptext'));`. XML, however, can be unlimited.

Comment: Hi there - I've read many of your articles and web sites.  Thank you for everything.  So if you run "select OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.sp_helptext')) obj_def for json path;" are you able to parse the JSON?

Comment: If I copy the results of that query into an online JSON parser it returns an error.  Based on that I didn't even bother sending it back to C#.  Seemingly no matter what I try when I copy/paste the results I'm not able to get the original formatting back.  Perhaps replacing /t/n would work.  But then Xml  sidesteps the whole issue and works perfectly :). It's for a SQL code generator built using T4 templates.   It uses the OpenAPI swagger.json file produced by a .NET Core WebAPI and it autogenerates all of the boilerplate code needed to support stored procedures.

Comment: If the endpoint already exists it autogenerates a script containing the procedure definitions, synonyms, etc. and enables application version control to be applied to stored procedures as extended properties

Comment: @SteveC Regarding the JSON output, there _might_ be a bug in how it outputs to both Results to Text and Results to File as it appears to chop the result into lines of 2048 chars each for some reason. That is what breaks the online JSON parsers as I just tried that myself and it only worked when I removed the actual newlines (not the escaped ones). I found that storing the JSON output to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` allowed it to work in both cases: `SET NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(MAX) = (select OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.sp_helptext')) AS [def] FOR JSON PATH); SELECT @B;`

Comment: @SteveC Also, I'm still not sure why you aren't just returning `SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'sys.sp_helptext')) AS [def];` as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. It's possible I'm missing something as I'm not familiar with either OpenAPI swagger.json files or the .NET Core WebAPI. It just seems like wrapping up as either XML or JSON only to parse it back to a string is two additional, yet unnecessary, steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120711/discussion-between-stevec-and-solomon-rutzky).

Answer (score 3):

```
sp_helptext 'sp_helptext'
    --If carriage return found  
    IF @CurrentPos != 0  
    begin  
        /*If new value for @Lines length will be > then the  
        **set length then insert current contents of @line  
        **and proceed.  
        */  
        while (isnull(LEN(@Line),0) + @BlankSpaceAdded + @CurrentPos-@BasePos + @LFCR) > @DefinedLength  
        begin  
            select @AddOnLen = @DefinedLength-(isnull(LEN(@Line),0) + @BlankSpaceAdded)  
            INSERT #CommentText VALUES  
            ( @LineId,  
              isnull(@Line, N'') + isnull(SUBSTRING(@SyscomText, @BasePos, @AddOnLen), N''))  
            select @Line = NULL, @LineId = @LineId + 1,  
                   @BasePos = @BasePos + @AddOnLen, @BlankSpaceAdded = 0  
        end  
        select @Line    = isnull(@Line, N'') + isnull(SUBSTRING(@SyscomText, @BasePos, @CurrentPos-@BasePos + @LFCR), N'')  
        select @BasePos = @CurrentPos+2  
        INSERT #CommentText VALUES( @LineId, @Line )  
        select @LineId = @LineId + 1  
        select @Line = NULL  
    end
```

K, so this is how sp_helptext does it. Wrap the results are a table function returning rows for CRLF characters returned by the object_definition.

Comment: good idea and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97188/how-to-output-more-than-4000-characters-in-sqlcmd?noredirect=1&lq=1) there is a similar one

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using SQL Server 2016, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and a [trick from Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175766/60085) to split on carriage-return/line-feed.

```
DECLARE 
  @olddelim nvarchar(32) = char(13) + Char(10),
  @newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (✏)

SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id('usp_radhe')), @olddelim, @newdelim), @newdelim);
```

Comment: and when I can't use the STRING_SPLIT function [I use this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199407/why-my-split-string-functions-are-not-working-with-large-object-definition?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to get back the original code with the line breaks, you can just query from the source (sys.sql_modules) with the datagrid output configured to retain line breaks.

> Tools>Options>Query Execution>SQL Server>Results to Grid
>
> - Check Retail CR/LF on copy or save
> - Maximum Characters Retrieved > Non XML data > (set as needed)

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'usp_radhe'
```