# why my split string functions are not working with large OBJECT_DEFINITION?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, string-searching, string-splitting

I have in one of my databases a stored procedure

called [PROCEDURE [repl].[usp_upd_repl_out_application]](https://gist.github.com/jjradha/b6e1eee41fb6eece46a9f128c061bf2d), that is not exactly a very clever stored procedure but it has over 389 lines.

As I need to change this stored procedure, I like to back it up to a table before any alteration, I am aware of source control applications and that should be the way to go, but I am happy doing things my way and it works for me.

it might be another case of [re-inventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel), but I still would like to know why my split strings functions are failing.

So while attempting to backup this stored procedure 
this stored procedure is object_id = 146815585 in my_database.

this works perfectly:

```
DECLARE 
  @olddelim nvarchar(32) = char(13) + Char(10),
  @newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (✏)
SELECT * 
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(146815585)
  , @olddelim
  , @newdelim)
  , @newdelim);
```

this also works nicely, although it is not the way I want it:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#radhe') is not null
   drop table #radhe

create table #radhe(i int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered, ln nvarchar(max))
insert into #radhe (ln)
exec sp_helptext '[repl].[usp_upd_repl_out_application]'
```

I have got [this split function from here](http://jahaines.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/splitting-delimited-string-part-1.html):

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_TVF_Split(@arr AS NVARCHAR(max), @sep AS NCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING,ENCRYPTION
AS
RETURN
WITH 
   L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1)       --2 rows
  ,L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B)    --4 rows (2x2)
  ,L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B)    --16 rows (4x4)
  ,L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B)    --256 rows (16x16)
  ,L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L3 AS A, L3 AS B)    --65536 rows (256x256)
  ,L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L4 AS A, L4 AS B)    --4,294,967,296 rows (65536x65536)
  ,Nums AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS N FROM L5)  
SELECT
(n - 1) - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(@arr, n-1), @sep, N'')) + 1 AS pos,
SUBSTRING(@arr, n, CHARINDEX(@sep, @arr + @sep, n) - n) AS element
FROM Nums
WHERE 
    n <= LEN(@arr) + 1
    AND SUBSTRING(@sep + @arr, n, 1) = @sep
    AND N<=1000
GO



DECLARE
@olddelim nvarchar(32) = Char(10) -- char(13) + Char(10), 
,@newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (?) 
SELECT m.*  
--INTO TableBackups.dbo._MMiorelli_20180305_repluspupdreploutapplication_140331_DB_ID_32 
from  dbo.fn_TVF_Split( OBJECT_DEFINITION ( 146815585),  @olddelim) m
```

it only returns 18 rows out of the 398

and this one below, only returns 60 out of the 398.

```
--=============================================
-- this is the SplitString function 
-- for use when we're below sql 2016
--=============================================
alter FUNCTION dbo.SplitString

    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim NVARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH ENCRYPTION
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
```

this is how I call this function:

```
 DECLARE  
@olddelim nvarchar(32) = Char(10) -- char(13) + Char(10), 
,@newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (?) 

SELECT m.*  
from  master.dbo.splitstring( OBJECT_DEFINITION ( 146815585),  @olddelim) m
```

returns 60 rows.

question:

is there a way I could modify my function `master.dbo.splitstring` so that it would return the whole 398 lines of the [procedure](https://gist.github.com/jjradha/b6e1eee41fb6eece46a9f128c061bf2d)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your `sys.all_objects` has enough rows to make this work.  It looks like your split routine is reading each *individual* character and concatenating it.  You have more characters in your stored procedure than you have rows in sys.all_objects.

I created and populated a `dbo.numbers` table with 100,000 rows and modified your code to use that instead of `sys.all_objects`.  I also included the row_number I was on to be able to see how the 'numbers' were being consumed.

You can really see what's going on if you run with output to text.

```
--drop table numbers
SELECT TOP 100000
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS Number
   INTO dbo.numbers
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2

--=============================================
-- this is the SplitString function 
-- for use when we're below sql 2016
--=============================================
alter FUNCTION dbo.SplitString

    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim NVARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH ENCRYPTION
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT * FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
            convert(varchar(10),number) as num,
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)
              FROM dbo.numbers) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );

DECLARE  
@olddelim nvarchar(32) = Char(10) -- char(13) + Char(10), 
,@newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (?) 

SELECT m.*  
from  dbo.splitstring( OBJECT_DEFINITION ( 727113781),  @olddelim) m
```

Comment: +1 for showing the number usage , it used over 12k numbers to read all that procedure.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli - glad you liked it ;)