# script all triggers in a database

Tags: sql-server, trigger, dynamic-sql, scripting, cursors

I have a few databases involved in replication as subscribers and they have triggers and are used by a different set of applications.

Every time I need to reinitialise those database I need to script the triggers, permissions and indexes, apply the snapshot and then re-apply those triggers, indexes and permissions.

Is there a script that I can use to script all the triggers of a current database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a whole lot simpler than what you have:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
  db          sysname,
  sch         sysname,
  obj         sysname,
  name        sysname,
  is_disabled bit,
  def         nvarchar(max)
);
GO

INSERT #tmp SELECT DB_NAME(), 
  s.name, o.name, t.name, 
  t.is_disabled, m.definition
FROM sys.triggers AS t
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
ON t.object_id = m.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON t.parent_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE parent_class = 1;
```

When you're ready to create them again:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += def 
  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'GO' 
  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
FROM #tmp;

SELECT @sql += N'DISABLE TRIGGER ' 
  + QUOTENAME(sch) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name)
  + N' ON ' 
  + QUOTENAME(sch) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(obj) + N';'
FROM #tmp WHERE is_disabled = 1;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Yes, you won't be able to validate the entire script is there, because SSMS won't output the entire value of `@sql`. See [this post for workarounds](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/).

Also, I don't know why you need the database as part of the dynamic script if you always know the database you're affecting, but there's a much safer way to make the database name dynamic without concatenating values and inviting SQL injection:

```
DECLARE @db sysname = N'AdventureWorks';

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

SET @sql = N'SELECT DB_NAME();';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a script that has helped me a lot:

```
-- script all triggers of the current database
--marcelo miorelli
--17-april-2018
DECLARE @CHECK_IF_TRIGGER_EXISTS BIT = 1

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Radhe') IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN 
      DROP TABLE #RADHE
   END 

CREATE TABLE #Radhe(
    DB sysname not null,
    parent_name nvarchar(600) not null,
    object_id int not null,
    trigger_name sysname not null,
    is_disabled bit,
    i int not null identity(1,1),
    [trigger_definition] NVARCHAR(MAX) not null
);

DECLARE @object_id int;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @theSQL nvarchar(max);
declare @DB sysname
declare @parent_name nvarchar(600)
declare @trigger_name sysname
declare @is_disabled bit


 select @DB = db_name(db_id())
 --select @DB 



    SELECT @SQL =
     '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                DECLARE 
                  @olddelim nvarchar(32) = char(13) + Char(10),
                  @newdelim nchar(1)     = NCHAR(9999); -- pencil (✏)

                SELECT the_db_name = quotename(db_name(db_id()))
                      ,parent_name  = @parent_name 
                      ,the_object_id = @obj_id
                      ,trigger_name  = @trigger_name
                      ,is_disabled   = @is_disabled
                      ,trigger_definition = [Value] 
                FROM master.dbo.splitstring(OBJECT_DEFINITION(@obj_id), @olddelim);
     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';

-- PRINT @SQL




BEGIN TRY

            DECLARE the_triggers CURSOR STATIC LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY 
            FOR
            SELECT 
             object_id=s.object_id
        ,parent_name  = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.parent_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.parent_id))
            ,trigger_name = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id))
            ,s.is_disabled
            FROM sys.triggers s
            WHERE 1=1


            OPEN the_triggers;
            FETCH NEXT FROM the_triggers 
            INTO @object_id,@parent_name,@trigger_name,@is_disabled;

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN

                SET @theSQL = 'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@DB) + 
                                    '.sys.sp_executesql @SQL'     + CHAR(10) +
                                    ',N''@obj_id int,@parent_name nvarchar(600),@trigger_name sysname,@is_disabled bit'',' + CHAR(10) + 
                                    '''' + CAST (@object_id as nvarchar)      + '''' +  ',' + 
                                    '''' + @parent_name   + '''' +  ',' + 
                                    '''' + @trigger_name  + '''' +  ',' + 
                                    '''' + CAST (COALESCE(@is_disabled,0) as nvarchar) + 
                                    '''' +';'    + CHAR(10)

                -------------------------------------------                        
                -- when @CHECK_IF_TRIGGER_EXISTS is on
                -- add code that checks whether the trigger exists
                -- and if it does drop it
                -------------------------------------------

                if @CHECK_IF_TRIGGER_EXISTS = 1 
                   BEGIN

                     INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition) values
                                 (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,'GO')

                     INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition) values
                                 (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,'use ' + QUOTENAME(db_name()))

                     INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition) values
                                 (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,'GO')

                     INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition) values
                                 (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,'if OBJECT_ID('+ '''' + @trigger_name + '''' + ') is not null')

                     INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition) values
                                 (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,'         drop trigger '+ @trigger_name + ' ')

                     INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition) values
                                 (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,'GO')


                   END 

                -------------------------------------------                        
                -- do the insert here
                -- the trigger source code
                -------------------------------------------

                --print @theSQL

                INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition)
                EXEC sys.sp_executesql @theSQL
                    , N'@SQL nvarchar(max) '
                    , @SQL = @sql

                -- add a GO after the trigger definition
                INSERT INTO #Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,trigger_definition) values
                            (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,'GO')

                -- fetch the next trigger
                FETCH NEXT FROM the_triggers 
                INTO @object_id,@parent_name,@trigger_name,@is_disabled;

            END

            ------------------------------------------- 
            BEGIN TRY
                --clean it up    
                CLOSE the_triggers;
                DEALLOCATE the_triggers;
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                --do nothing
            END CATCH
            ------------------------------------------- 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

            ------------------------------------------- 
            BEGIN TRY
                --clean it up    
                CLOSE the_triggers;
                DEALLOCATE the_triggers;
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                --do nothing
            END CATCH
            ------------------------------------------- 

    DECLARE @ERRORMESSAGE    NVARCHAR(512),
            @ERRORSEVERITY   INT,
            @ERRORNUMBER     INT,
            @ERRORSTATE      INT,
            @ERRORPROCEDURE  SYSNAME,
            @ERRORLINE       INT,
            @XASTATE         INT

    SELECT
            @ERRORMESSAGE     = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ERRORSEVERITY    = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ERRORNUMBER      = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @ERRORSTATE       = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ERRORPROCEDURE   = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
            @ERRORLINE        = ERROR_LINE()

    SET @ERRORMESSAGE = 
    (
    SELECT                    CHAR(13) +
      'Message:'         +    SPACE(1) + @ErrorMessage                           + SPACE(2) + CHAR(13) +
      'Error:'           +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorNumber)      + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Severity:'        +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorSeverity)    + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'State:'           +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorState)       + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Routine_Name:'    +    SPACE(1) + COALESCE(@ErrorProcedure,'')            + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Line:'            +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ErrorLine)        + SPACE(1) + CHAR(13) +
      'Executed As:'     +    SPACE(1) + SYSTEM_USER + SPACE(1)                             + CHAR(13) +
      'Database:'        +    SPACE(1) + DB_NAME() + SPACE(1)                               + CHAR(13) +
      'OSTime:'          +    SPACE(1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,121)        + CHAR(13) 
    )

    --We can also save the error details to a table for later reference here.
    RAISERROR (@ERRORMESSAGE,16,1)

END CATCH

SELECT * FROM #RADHE
```

Comment: master.dbo.splitstring source code can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199407/why-my-split-string-functions-are-not-working-with-large-object-definition)